# 404 page not found on pagination in home page while navigating to next page

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I am new to wordpress. I am trying to paginate custom post type I have created on index page. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong . Here's the code :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 
   'post_type'          => 'Casinos',
'posts_per_page' => 8,
'paged' => $paged, 
'meta_key'          => 'rank',
'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
'order'             => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

     //Display content

    endwhile; 

$total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){

    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => 'page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
        'next_text'    => __('next »'),
    ));
}

endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The page navigation links are showing correctly but when I clicks for another page it shows 404 page not found. I am not using any plugin for this . Do I have to use one? Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any research at all? :( you can not just pull pagination out of thin air... I think there is a (almost exactly same) question asked once a month (if not more). Look at the related section in the sidebar

Comment: I tried using wp-paginate plugin initially, but as I am new to wordpress I couldn't make it work for custom post type. Can you suggest a sample  code for paginating custom post types?

Comment: I tested this on other page .It is working fine .The problem is its not working on index page. What might be the problem?

Comment: I set permalink as :http://localhost/site/%postname%/. Is there any problem with permalink setting?

Comment: it is not magic, you can not just decide to add whatever you want to a url and hope that by magic it will get parsed as you expect it. If pagination is not available for the specific url, you will get 404

Comment: you should seriously read the questions and answers regarding it

Comment: Try to remove the `base` and `format` from the `array` passed on to `paginate_links()`. Or comment them out like this: `//'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',`